# NullPointerException using java.util.Arrays.sort()

Tags: java, sorting

This program reads the lines of an input file and stores them into the array words. Then each element in words[] is put into a character array and sorted alphabetically. Each sorted character array is assigned to a string and those strings populate another array sortedWords. I need to sort the elements in the sortedWords array. I get a NullPointerException when I use Arrays.sort(sortedWords).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a file name: ");
    System.out.flush();

    String filename = scanner.nextLine();
    File file = new File(filename);

    String[] words = new String[10];
    String[] sortedWords = new String[10];

    try {   
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String line = br.readLine();
        int i = 0;

        while(line != null) {
            words[i] = line.toString();    // assigns lines into the array
            line = br.readLine();    // this will eventually set line to null, terminating the loop

            String signature = words[i];                        
            char[] characters = signature.toCharArray();        
            Arrays.sort(characters);
            String sorted = new String(characters);               

            sortedWords[i] = sorted;    // assigns each signature into the array
            sortedWords[i] = sortedWords[i].replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").toLowerCase();    // removes non-alphabetic chars and makes lowercase
            Arrays.sort(sortedWords); 

            System.out.println(words[i] + " " + sortedWords[i]);
            i++;
        }     
    } 

    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hopefully your file only has 10 lines.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take the `sort` out of the `while` loop.

```
int i = 0;
while(line != null) {
   ...
   i++;
}
Arrays.sort(sortedWords, 0, i);
```

The problem is that you call `sort` before you finished populating the `sortedWords` array. The array therefore still contains `null` strings and these cause the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Still gives me a `NullPointerException`

Comment: The input file will also need to have exactly 10 lines for this to work.  If there are more than 10 the array index will be out of bounds and if there are less than 10, the same null pointer exception will occur

Comment: Your file probably doesn't have 10 lines. Consider using `List<String>` and `Collections.sort`

Comment: @G_A How can I account for more/less than 10 lines while still using an array? I understand an ArrayList or Collection is a better data structure but I'm limited to Arrays (homework).

Comment: @dk1 Updated answer. You can give `Arrays.sort` a start and end index.

Comment: @cyon Thanks, that's what I needed. I should add that since `Arrays.sort` is outside of the while loop, I used `sortedWords.length` as the end index.